# Insert a comma in address field before number of house

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have a table with a lot of address field that have no comma 
between street name and house number. 
Something like:

```
"VIA MILANO 123"
"VIA MILANO    A123"
"VIA 11 MILANO      AA123"
```

What I need is a SQL that insert the comma before 
the last group that contain numbers... like:

```
"VIA MILANO, 123"
"VIA MILANO,    A123"
"VIA 11 MILANO,      AA123"
```

I found something on net but a lot of thinks is not work on IBM DB".

Can anybody help me please ? 
I have more than 100000 recs in the file to solve.

Thanks in advance
Denis

Comment: We have V7R2M0 version. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not familiar with IBM DB, so I am just gonna give you an idea of what I would use on Oracle DB. SUBSTR(:X, 0, INSTR(:X, ' ', -1)) || ',' || SUBSTR(:X, INSTR(:X, ' ', -1)), if this works, then you could just do an update that does this, or whatever you need

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tine... but the field is 40 chars and I can have a lot of blank spaces at the end of the field. I must found the last number, then I must found the blank space begin from last number to the left ... I think. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Db2 for i 7.2 supports the REGEXP_REPLACE function

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzscaregexp_replace.htm

Try this

```
SELECT c, REGEXP_REPLACE(c,'(\s+\S*\d+\s*$)',',\1') 
FROM TABLE(
    VALUES
     ('VIA MILANO 123     ')
    ,('VIA MILANO A123    ')
    ,('VIA 11 MILANO AA123')
) AS t(c)
```

returns

```
 C                      2
 -------------------    --------------------
 VIA MILANO 123         VIA MILANO, 123
 VIA MILANO A123        VIA MILANO, A123
 VIA 11 MILANO AA123    VIA 11 MILANO, AA123
```

Regular Expressions provide a powerful and flexible way to manipulate strings , and it is worth learning about them.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzregexp_like.htm#rbafzregexp_like__regexp_likecontrol

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul, but in my AS400 the returs is tha same as the input values :-(

Comment: It should work. How about if you run my example, does that put the comma's in? I don't have an iSeries to test it on, but it works on DB2 LUW 11.1

Comment: I just copy/paste your example and the output is equal at the input... I mean that the output have not the coma. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: I also control the International Components for Unicode (ICU) option and is installed on my iSeries... Thanks again

Comment: Can anybodu help me please to understand why this SQL is work on Oracle and is not work on iSeries 7.2 ? Thanks again.

Comment: @Denis The ibm i-series v.2 docs for regular expressions do not mention the character class escapes for \s, \S, \d. This may explain the behaviour on i-series. Suggest you recode or open a ticket with ibm support to get their confirmation whether these character-class-escapes are supported in 7.2 or not

Comment: Dear all, 
I found the problem (for future users) 

My client access emulation (the green screen) 
has the code-page on Italian-Euro in the communication configuration. 

Now that I put it on 037 United States it's work :-) 

Thanks a lot all for your support. 
Denis